# Measurement with any number of outcomes can be performed as a sequence of measurements with two outcomes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-measurements

I was reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0503017), at the bottom of the first page, it mentions "It is easy to show that measurement with any number of outcomes can be performed as a sequence of measurements with two outcomes." How can it be possible? Would really appreciate a mathematical explanation.

Edit: I am familiar with the concepts of quantum mechanics primarily from The introduction to QM by Griffiths. I have just begun reading about weak measurements.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that observables are represented by self-adjoint operators, and that a self-adjoint operator can be written as a linear combination of mutually commuting projection operators (if its spectrum is discrete)? Since you're asking for a mathematical explanation, giving a little more information about what you already know about the relevant principles of quantum theory might help people tailor their answers. Even a brief sentence like "I'm familiar with the principles of quantum theory as described in [name a reference here]" could help.

Answer (score 1):

Any classical gate (AND, OR, NOT, NAND, AND) has two outcomes: $0$ and $1$. Using a sequence of such gates, you can create a measurement with multiple outcomes. One simple example is the [adder circuit](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Halfadder.gif#/media/File:Halfadder.gif). And it can lead to far complex circuits like [counters](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Asynchronous-counter2.svg#/media/File:Asynchronous-counter2.svg), [registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_register), integrated circuits etc.